# Prestashop 1.7 module : Need to get "Country" and "State" names, "Products" and "Order message"

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-modules

I am developing a module, it gets *order details* when order statut is changed to *"shipped"* by admin, to post them to a third party application with api. I am using Prestashop **V 1.7.7.0.**

I still need to get **"country"** and **"state" names**, **"products"** and **"order message"**. How can i do that please?

Also, the module can't be installed in prestashop. Is my code right?

**Need help please. Thanks**

```
public function hookActionOrderStatusPostUpdate($params)
    {
        if($params['newOrderStatus']->id == 13)
        {
            $order = new Order((int)$params['id_order']);
            $address = new Address((int)$order->id_address_delivery);
            $customer = new Customer((int)($address->id_customer));
            $country = new Country((int)($address->id_country));
            $state = new Country((int)($address->id_state));
            
            $tel_cl = $address->phone;
            $name_lastname_cl = $address->lastname . ' ' . $address->firstname;
            $country_cl = **Not yet**;
            $state_cl = **Not yet**;
            $adress_cl = $address->address1 . ' ' . $address->address2;
            $tel_2_cl = $address->phone_mobile
            $products = **Not yet**;
            $quantity = "1"
            $cod = $order->total_paid
            $note = **Not yet(order message)**;

            $Url_str = 'http://example.com/api/set_parcel_post.php?id=123&tel_cl='.$tel_cl.'&name_lastname_cl='.$name_lastname_cl.'&country_cl='.$country_cl.'&state_cl='.$state_cl.'&address_cl='.$address_cl.'&tel_2_cl='.$tel_2_cl.'&products='.$products.'&cod='.$cod.'&Quantity='.$Quantity.'&note='.$note;

    $json = file_get_contents($Url_str);
    $result = json_decode($json);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "the module can't be installed in prestashop" mean? That has no sense.

Comment: You can check Country class and Zone class and use function to get there names by the Id from address

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply, @Fran Cerezo when i try to install my module, i got an error msg. So i think i have an error in the code.. Is my code right ? Thanks

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help @Arun Vishwakarama, i did that, but i still have an error when i try to install my module, Is my code right ? Thanks

Comment: For installation please add error message and your module file code so can see if any error

Comment: Watch why module does not install in error.log , we need info to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate a Country object using an id_state so this:

```
 $state = new Country((int)($address->id_state));
```

is wrong and should be

```
 $state = new State((int) $address->id_state);
```

So you can get the state name like `$state->name`,
To get the product orders you can use `$order->getProducts();` which will return an array filled with the order products and its information(name,price,etc..)

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help @GaimZz . I added this : is my code right please?

$OrderProducts = $order->getProducts();
`foreach($OrderProducts as $product)
 {$products = $products . {$product.name} . <br>;
 $quantity = $quantity + {$product.quantity};
   }`

Comment: I suggest you try using and editor for php, or some kind of parsing tools that kindly prompts you about syntactic errors, for example atom, vscode, sublimetext3, etc... The code you pasted isnt well parsed so im not sure, have you event tried?

Comment: Ok i got it, no i didn't try yet. I will try your advice. Thank you very much for your help @GaimZz